# Determinant of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  & 4\\ 
 0& 0 &3 \\ 
0 &0  &-1 
\end{bmatrix}$, then we are asked to find the determinant of $A^{17}+A^{10}-I$

My approach is that the characteristic equation of this matrix gives $x^{3}=x$ so $A^{17}=A$ and $A^{10}=A^{2}$ hence $A^{17}+A^{10}-I$=$A^{2}+A-I$

Now $A^{2}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  & 6\\ 
 0& 0 &-3 \\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $A^{2}+A$=$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &4  & 10\\ 
 0& 0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $A^{2}+A-I$=$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &4  & 10\\ 
 0& -1 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &-1 
\end{bmatrix}$ which, because its lower triangular has a determinant of $1(-1)(-1)=1$;

But apparently the answer in my textbook for this is 0, could it be an error in the textbook or am i wrong somewhere in the reasoning, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I get the same answer as you ... Weird .

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C2%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C3%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%7D%7D%5E17%2B%7B%7B1%2C2%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C3%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%7D%7D%5E10-%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D) agrees with you.

Comment: Thanks, it must be a typo then!!

Comment: Your reasoning is fine (Cayley-Hamilton-Theorem)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to get the determinant is to see that
$$A^{17}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &*  & *\\ 
 0& 0 & * \\ 
0 &0  &-1 
\end{bmatrix} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad A^{10}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &*  & *\\ 
 0& 0 & * \\ 
0 &0  &1
\end{bmatrix}$$

so $$A^{17} + A^{10} - I =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &*  & *\\ 
 0& -1 & * \\ 
0 &0  & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore the determinant is, indeed, equal to $1$.

Comment: Great downvote !